# How to run a app in the background forever?

Tags: android, background-service

I want to make a app that runs in the background,even after removing it from the recent apps.

Comment: create a service and keep it running in background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an android app to always run in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background)

Comment: Hi there,

Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50639788/5479863

Answer (score 0):

If you device  is Oreo or above Oreo u need to  use Firebase JobDispatcher, Alarm Manger etc for long Running Service. For device below Oreo needs normal Service.

There are Some Limitations For Runnng long Services in Devices With Oreo and Higher. Please Refere the Documentation for more details